# Integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}x\log(1+kx^2)\,dx$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to evaluate: 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}x\log(1+kx^2)\,dx$$
Basically am evaluating value of $\log(1+c\chi^2)$ where $\chi^2$ is $\chi$-squared distributed

Comment: Since $e^xx\log(1+kx^2)$ does not converge to zero, but actually diverges to infinity, this integral is fairly easy.

Comment: I am getting Expi() functions in between and am stuck of that

Comment: So, it isn't obviously $-\infty$? Or did you want $\int_0^{X}$ and not $\int_{0}^\infty$?

Comment: If the question is wrong, fix the question, don't just add to the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you would have meant to write $e^{-x}$, or $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^0$ , the integral would still not be expressible in terms of *elementary* functions and constants, since a simple substitution of the form $kx^2=\sinh^2t$ would immediately create an expression in terms of [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function), and their various derivatives.

Comment: By using numerical methods based on their fast-converging series expansion.

Comment: Notice that the integral evaluates to $I'\bigg(-\dfrac12\bigg)$, where $I(\alpha)$ is the expression defined in [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v2XSM.png) picture, with $k=\beta^2>0$.